# Where do I place or how do I install my own Python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

Sorry for the super-simple question, it's just that I haven't found a proper answer here (that worked for me).

I've just wrote some demo Python code, a Python module (logically speaking) to be exact, and I want to import this and use it.

Where should I place my `module_x.py` file? (I'm running on **Windows**)

I've checked that all the module `.py` files are placed under `..\Python27\Lib` directory, but placing my file there doesn't work for me –
when I try to run `import module_x` I get this error message:

```
ImportError: No module named module_x
```

Comment: Try doing `import sys; print sys.path`, this will display where your Python is searching.

Comment: just do `import filename` then `filename.function` from the file that you want to use

Comment: @MartinEvans Do you know any good C++ tutorials for beginners? I want to start something new. I already know java, javascript, and python.

Comment: "import filename" just fails - as I said in the question

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax I got a bunch of directories as an output. Which one is the correct one?

Comment: When you do `import filename` what does it do?

Comment: Also the module you should be in the same folder as the program that you are trying to call it from

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to put it in the same folder as the script that uses it.

If even this does not work, check to see if Windows has snuck in a file extension such ".txt" that isn't visible in the way you are viewing the file name.

As you have time, please read how to deal with modules from a manual or book to learn to do it the right way.